# elasticsearch: no known master node, scheduling a retry

Tags: elasticsearch

Anyone able to help me with steps to fix/diagnose an elastic cluster which has fallen over randomly with the following errors please?  version 7.3.1.

```
elasticsearch      | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-06T09:30:49,585+0000", "level": "DEBUG", "component": "o.e.a.a.i.c.TransportCreateIndexAction", "cluster.name": "xxx", "node.name": "bex",  "message": "no known master node, scheduling a retry"  }   
elasticsearch      | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-06T09:30:50,741+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "xxx", "node.name": "bex",  "message": "path: /_bulk, params: {}" ,   
elasticsearch      | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized, SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];",
```

It has been running without any issues for ages.

Comment: code indentation required.

Comment: @surajs1n already fixed. :)